# Display the data/messages for the Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I want to read messages from service bus from a certain date, But my code is not reading messages.
In service Bus is there any option like setting a trigger,
I have tried the below code from microsoft doc but still not able to recive messages.

**Message handler**

```
 public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        await AdditionAsync();

        return 0;
    }

    static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        var body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(body);
        if (body.Contains("My Label")) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {body} from subscription: <TOPIC-SUBSCRIPTION-NAME>");
        } 
    }
```

**Error handler**

```
 static Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static async Task AdditionAsync()
    {

        var clientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions
        {
            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
        };

        var client = new ServiceBusClient(
            "Connection string",
             clientOptions);
        
        var test = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions()
        {

        }
     
        var processor = client.CreateProcessor("TOpic", "subscription", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());
  
        try
        {
           
            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

            
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

            
            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Wait for a minute and then press any key to end the processing");
            Console.ReadKey();

            
            Console.WriteLine("\nStopping the receiver...");
            await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped receiving messages");
        }
        finally
        {
            
            await processor.DisposeAsync();
            await client.DisposeAsync();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Can we change the code and recive the messages on perticular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a service bus in azure portal
Now go to resource and go to Service Bus Explorer where messages need to be sent.
Before that create a subscription in service bus and now send messages as below.
[image]
Now to retrieve the messages on a particular date use the code below

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using System;
string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
string entityName = "<queue_or_topic_name>";
ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(entityName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
{
    ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete, // Delete messages immediately after receiving them
    MaxWaitTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) // Maximum time to wait for a message to become available
});
Console.Write("Enter a date and time (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss): ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (!DateTimeOffset.TryParse(input, out DateTimeOffset dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date and time format.");
    return;
}
while ((message = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync(dateTime)) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received message with body: {message.Body}");
}
await receiver.CloseAsync();
await client.DisposeAsync();
```

Run the above code by replacing the connection string, subscription name and topic name. I did the same in my environment and got the message on a required date.
[image]